# Discord.js v14 DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, discord.js

To make a new bot, I wrote the code and run it. But I saw error happen every time I run my code. I don't know the cause about this error. And I want to solve this. Please help.

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\gims3\OneDrive\바탕 화면\discord.js V14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\gims3\OneDrive\바탕 화면\discord.js V14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1021:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\gims3\OneDrive\바탕 화면\discord.js V14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:862:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\gims3\OneDrive\바탕 화면\discord.js V14\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async client.handleCommands (C:\Users\gims3\OneDrive\바탕 화면\discord.js V14\src\functions\handlers\handleCommands.js:27:7) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: { '0': [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1043561701905272915/commands'
}
```

My command handler:

```
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v10");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleCommands = async () => {
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/commands`);
    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
      const commandsFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

      const { commands, commandArray } = client;
      for (const file of commandsFiles) {
        const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
      }
    }

    const clientId = "1043561701905272915";
    const guildId = "775692469315698739";
    const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(process.env.token);
    try {
      console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId, guildId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });

      console.log("Successfully reloaded  application (/) commands.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
};
```

I read discord developer portal but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The error is coming from one of your command files. Check them, and check the `name` field.

Comment: Okay, I'll check them! Thanks a lot!!